# Discord.js User Presence Customize

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I use a discord bot command, for the purpose of showing the specific person's discord presence, let's say his presence is set on 'Do Not Disturb' a.k.a dnd.
I want this line :
`**• Discord Username:**  ${user.username}`,
lets say that specific person is on online, I want it to say 'Online' with a capital 'O', but it shows it as 'online'. Or the same thing for 'dnd', i want it as 'Do Not Disturb'.
I've defined user as : message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
Any ways to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Presence = {
    "online": "Online",
    "dnd": "Do Not Disturb",
    "idle": "Idle",
    "offline": "Offline"
}

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "-presence") {
        const User = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        message.channel.send(Presence[User.presence.status]);
    };
});
```