# Discord.js How to use emojies in a embed showing user presence

Tags: discord.js

There is a pastebin on the end with the same code for easier access. I wonder how instead of sending an individual message in the channel. To just show it in the embed itself.

Discord.js = 11.5.1

No, I do not want to update to V12 just yet most of the code seems to work equal, however (At least in my bot)

So if I want to example have the "BLACK_HEART" Shown in the embed what do I do?

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const color = require("../../color.json");
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports = {
    name: "userinfo",
    aliases: ["ui"],
    description: "SOMETHING",
    usage: "ALSO SOMETHING",
    run: (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete();
        
        const rMember = message.mentions.members.first()
        
        if(!rMember) 
            return message.channel.send("Please mention a user you want to see the status's off.")

            // switch (rMember.presence.status) {
            //     case 'online':
            //         ('<:Online:720645133699121292> | Online');
            //         break;
            //     case 'idle':
            //         ('<:Idle:720645133720223794> | Idle');
            //         break;
            //     case 'dnd':
            //         ('<:Offline:720645133577748491> | Offline');
            //         break;
            //     case 'offline':
            //         ('<:disagree:720645133065912381> | Offline');
            //         break;
            // }

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor(color.orange)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setTitle(`Central Operating System | User Info`)
            .addField(`Username`, rMember.user.username)
            
            .addField(`User ID`, rMember.user.id, true)
            .addField(`User Discriminator`, rMember.user.discriminator, true)
            .addField(`User Bot?`, rMember.user.bot, true)
            .addBlankField()

            .addField(`Account Creation Date`, `${moment(rMember.user.createdAt)}`, true)
            .addField(`Account Joined Server`, `${moment(rMember.user.joinedAt)}`, true)
            .addBlankField()

            .addField(`User Status`, rMember.presence.status, true) // <- I want this to show with emoji's
            .addField(`User Precense`, `UN-USED IN THIS BUILD`, true)
            .addField(`Avatar URL Link`, rMember.user.displayAvatarURL)

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

[THIS PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/THtbtkT0)

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Hell guys,

I like the help that you are giving me however it is not what i am looking for. let me explain it just a little better for you guys.

Let's say I mention @user1 I want to be able to see their respective presence whether they are online or offline, idle or DND. The blackheart resembles Offline but what if they are online it would make no sense to send a black heart.

Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 1):

Default:

```js
Go To Emojipedia & Copy Emote And Paste It In Your Code
```

Non-Animated Custom Emotes:

```js
<:Name:ID>
```

Animated Custom Emotes:

```js
<a:Name:ID>
```

BLACK_HEART:

```js
message.channel.send(" | Back Heart")
```

How To Get Custom Animated Emoji ID?

Nitro:
Put \ Before Animated Emoji & Send Message To A Channel And Copy ID <a:Name:**ID**> (<a:CuteDance:**709346456045355010**>)
Without Nitro:
Copy Emoji Link & Get ID From Link https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/**ID**.gifv=1
(https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/**709346456045355010**.gif?v=1)

How To Get Custom Non-Animated Emoji ID?
Put \ Before Emoji & Send Message To A Channel And Copy ID <:Name:**ID**> (<:CuteAww:**709347796276478022**>)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of emojis in Discord. The custom ones and the other ones which are already in discord. You can add custom emojis by entering in this format `<EmojiName:EmojiId>`. To obtain any emojis name and id, use the backslash '`\`' before the emoji. For eg. if my emojis name is `x` and id `720645133699121292`, if I use `\:x:` it'll return <:x:720645133699121292:>. For under Unicode emojis you can use `\` before the emoji or if you use windows, use `WINDOWS_KEY + PERIOD (.)` and you'll get a set of emojis. Here in your case is a Unicode emoji [black_heart], so use . I'm unsure where you need to use the emoji in your code, and this seems to be a general question so I don't think code is required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using a constructor and an array. So the code now looks like this.

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const color = require("../../color.json");
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports = {
    name: "userinfo",
    aliases: ["ui"],
    description: "SOMETHING",
    usage: "ALSO SOMETHING",
    run: (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete();
        
        const rMember = message.mentions.members.first()
        
        if(!rMember) 
            return message.channel.send("Please mention a user you want to see the status's off.")

            const presence = {
                "online": "<:Online:720645133699121292> | Online",
                "idle": "<:Idle:720645133720223794> | Idle",
                "dnd": "<:Offline:720645133577748491> | Offline",
                "offline": "<:disagree:720645133065912381> | Offline"
            }

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor(color.orange)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setTitle(`Central Operating System | User Info`)
            //.setDescription(`Currently Work In Progres. . . .`)
            .addField(`Username`, rMember.user.username)
            
            .addField(`User ID`, rMember.user.id, true)
            .addField(`User Discriminator`, rMember.user.discriminator, true)
            //.addField(`User Verified?`, rMember.user.verified)
            .addField(`User Bot?`, rMember.user.bot, true)
            .addBlankField()

            .addField(`Account Creation Date`, `${moment(rMember.user.createdAt)}`, true)
            .addField(`Account Joined Server`, `${moment(rMember.user.joinedAt)}`, true)
            .addBlankField()

            .addField(`User Status`, presence[rMember.presence.status], true)
            .addField(`User Precense`, `UN-USED IN THIS BUILD`, true)
            .addField(`Avatar URL Link`, rMember.user.displayAvatarURL)

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

I thank you all for trying to help!

I found my answer here.
[Discord.js User Presence Customize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134878/discord-js-user-presence-customize?rq=1)